# Does async in 4.5 imply a new thread is spun up just by entering the function?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.5

Or do I have to use Task.Run within the method to make sure each function exists on its own thread?  I'm trying to see if there's any wisdom in this practice I see in the code I'm working on.

```
public async Task<string> GetAStringAfterSyncProcessing(string processThis) {
       return await Task.Run(async () => { 
              var processThis2 = processThis + ",";
              var processThis3 = processThis2 + ",";
              var nowImDone = processThis3 + ",";
              return nowImDone;
       });
}
```

I have a feeling that this is unintended design, since it makes it impossible to walk through each line while debugging. So I'm wondering if I'd be right in explaining to others that async automatically implies the creating of a new thread so that the function is only called when await or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() is used.  Thanks

Comment: I suggest you start with my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html); I have a number of good followup resources at the end of that post.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. So it would stand to reason that unless the nature of the function is asynchronous, then there's no benefit to wrapping the function body in a Task.Run, no?

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way, no. `Task.Run` is useful in code where you know you're running on a UI thread and need to offload some work onto a background thread. But `Task.Run` shouldn't be used in "library" (general-purpose) code, generally speaking. It's not normal to implement `async` methods just be wrapping them in `Task.Run`; `Task.Run` is a better fit for *calling* methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `async` itself does *not* create a new thread.

And there's no point in using `async`/`await` in the code you've demonstrated. It's mostly equivalent to:

```
public Task<string> GetAStringAfterSyncProcessing(string processThis) {
    return Task.Run(() => { 
        var processThis2 = processThis + ",";
        var processThis3 = processThis2 + ",";
        var nowImDone = processThis3 + ",";
        return nowImDone;
    });
}
```

(I've removed the async lambda too, which was unnecessary.)

Next:

> So I'm wondering if I'd be right in explaining to others that async automatically implies the creating of a new thread so that the function is only called when await or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() is used.

No, that's definitely not the right explanation at all. It's hard to give the full low-down on it in just an SO answer, but I strongly suggest you go and read the [MSDN resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) on what async/await is actually about. There's an expectation that whatever you await will be inherently asynchronous - where that's because it starts a thread itself, or because it doesn't *need* a thread in order to be asynchronous (e.g. async IO).

Comment: and it seems strange that there is an inner `async` lambda rather than just a regular lambda.  It gets unwrapped by Task.Run, but that seems unnecessary. Am I missing something?

Comment: All of our functions must use the async keyword to enable await if it's needed.

Comment: @user2141723: No, they really don't. You can await any task, so as long as your method returns a task, you're fine to await the result.